# Selecionar mais de um item com a tag select

Tags: javascript, html5, select

Estou com um problema, a tag  do html permite que o usuário selecione somente uma opção dentre todos da lista, no entanto preciso selecionar mais de um item do select, como fazer isso utilizando somente JS? Preciso selecionar quais dias da semana para realizar um evento, como um alarme.

```html
<select name="diasSemana">
   <option value="1">Segunda</option>
   <option value="2">Terça</option>
   <option value="3">Quarta</option>
   <option value="4">Quinta</option>
   <option value="5">Sexta</option>
   <option value="6">Sábado</option>
   <option value="7">Domingo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Vitor, dá para selecionar mais de um elemento no select, sem javascript, basta apenas declarar a propriedade **multiple** dentro do select, pode ler mais aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode criar um select normal com a tag multiple e o usuário seleciona com ctrl as opções multiplas no seu select, quando passado por post, recebera algo como:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <select name="opcoes" multiple>
    <option value="opcao1">opcao1</option>
    <option value="opcao2">opcao2</option>
    <option value="opcao3">opcao3</option>
    <option value="opcao4">opcao4</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

opcoes=opcao1&opcoes=opcao2&opcoes=opcao3
```

Tem uma documentação sobre o multiselect no w3schools, da uma olhadinha:  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Comment: Eu vi essa opção, so achei chato a utilização, ter que apertar control para selecionar mais de um, muitos usuários não sabe disso, inclusive eu não sabia kkk